# Why would I need to lazy load NGRX state as Features?

Tags: ngrx

I am trying to understand NGRX Feature slices, and it seems like it merges the state with the global state, which defeats any purpose I can think of to create a feature slice.

Global state doesn't need to be lazy loaded because it is based on RXJS, so the state won't exist until their is a subscriber. So it doesn't need to be lazy loaded.

If it's merged with the global state, then that module won't have it's own isolated piece of state.

And I can't find anything on the NGRX website about Features beyond "It exists and you can use schematics to quick-generate them". So what is the benefit of Features, and why would I need to create one?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that having a single source of truth is one of the main principles when using NgRx (or Redux). It can start out as a "smaller" state tree, but every additional slice will be appended to the main state tree. (I don't know if redux has a "lazy loading" feature, or that it already initializes with the whole state tree).

The main advantage you get with slicing your state tree into multiple features (or slices), is that it's easier to maintain. You don't have to do this, but it will make things easier in the future. Just like you don't have a single large file that contains all of your code, instead you split them up into multiple source files. Each with its own responsibility.

Additionally, it also improves the performance. When feature A is updated, only the selectors that use feature A will be retriggered. When you have a single state tree, more selectors will be executed. (just like you would split up a database in multiple tables)